# $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a semisimple ring provided n is square-free

Tags: ring-theory, modules, semi-simple-rings

Show that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a semisimple ring if n is square-free..

Some articles suggests that we can use Chinese remainder theorem. But I can't exactly figure out how to do that.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Try to show the statement for a special case $n = p^e$ ($p$: prime) first: $\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z}$ is semisimple if and only if $e > 1$.

Comment: @orat are you sure about the statement? in my question n is square free

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand your question (I thought iff, not if) and misstated a hint. Well, I'm pretty sure that it is straightforward then. What can you say from CRT?

Comment: Recall that an artinian ring $R$ is semisimple iff the Jacobson radical $J(R)$ is zero and $J(R_1 \times \dotsb \times R_k) = J(R_1) \times \dotsb \times J(R_k)$ in general.

Answer (score 0):

Take the prime factorization $n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_n^{e_n}$.
Then $\phi:{\Bbb Z}/n{\Bbb Z}\rightarrow \prod_i {\Bbb Z}/p_i^{e_i}$ defined by
$m\mapsto (m\;{\rm mod}\;p_i^{e_i})$ is a ring isomorphism.
If $n$ is square-free, then $e_1=\ldots=e_n=1$ and ${\Bbb Z}/p_i{\Bbb Z}$ is a field and so simple. Thus your ring is a product of simple rings and so semisimple.
The proof of the ring isomorphy (surjectivity) requires the Chinese remainder theorem.